# Removing non integers from a grep obtained string w/ Python and Bash

Tags: python, bash, filter, grep, findall

I am using `grep` to grab the text out of a file:

```
NELECT = 44.0000   total number of electrons,
```

and I need to save the number as a variable. I have tried a handful of methods I have found here such as using filters and `findall`. For some reason I can only get it to separate one zero.

So far the code looks like this:

```
wd=os.getcwd()
electrons=str(os.system("grep 'NELECT' "+wd+"/OUTCAR"))
VBM=(re.findall('\d+', electrons))
print VBM
```

And in return I get ['0'].

Comment: Somehow that caused the output to be 256.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using the shell vs reading the file in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of os.system is the exit status of the command, not the output of the command -- see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

```
$ cat OUTCAR 
NELECT = 44.0000   total number of electrons,

$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> result = os.system("grep 'NELECT' "+os.getcwd()+"/OUTCAR")
NELECT = 44.0000   total number of electrons,
>>> result
0
```

The "NELECT" line was just printed by grep to stdout, but not captured in the result variable

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> result2 = check_output(["grep", "NELECT", os.getcwd()+"/OUTCAR"])
>>> result2
'NELECT = 44.0000   total number of electrons,\n'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', result2)
['44', '0000']
```

Or, don't call out to grep, read the file yourself

```
>>> import os
>>> import re
>>> with open(os.getcwd() + "/OUTCAR") as f:
...   for line in f:
...     if "NELECT" in line:
...       digits = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
...       break
...
>>> digits
['44', '0000']
```

Or, maybe don't use a regular expression:

```
>>> words = line.split()
>>> words[2]
'44.0000'
>>> int(float(words[2]))
44
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `electrons` has output specified? For me this regex returns list with two elements: `['44', '000']` and that's expected behavior. So most probably there is something wrong with grep call.

Your regex won't retrieve whole `44.000` as `\d+` catches only continuous digit strings, no dot symbols. To get whole number use something like `\b\d+\.\d+\b` which means: any word (`\b` means word beginning/ending, dot must be escaped as `.` in regex matches any character) that contains at least 1 digit, dot and at least 1 more digit. If dot is optional, then something like this: `\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b` (`(?:)` creates group that will not be captured so your output will still be single element list).

Note that `re.findall` will return list of string matches. To retrieve number from first match: `float(VBM[0])`

Edit. Forgot to add: avoid using print statement, it works oddly with tuples and is completely removed in Python 3. Python 2 support ends in 2020 so it's better to prepare. You can replace print statement with Python 3 print function by adding `from __future__ import print_function` at the file beginning.